# IIS PHP and NET USE command

Tags: php, shell, iis

My environment:
Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1
IIS 7.5 (using Windows Authentication)
PHP 5.5

I'm working on a script that accesses files in a password protected network location. The only way I could think of accomplishing this was by temporarily mounting it to a drive letter then working with the directory. However, when testing the script through a browser, I cannot get any output or result when I use the following code:

```
shell_exec("net use W: \"\\\\server\\secureshare\" secretpw /user:domain\\gdesoto /persistent:no");
```

However, if I run this using command line, it works perfectly fine.

As far as I can tell, all other commands run fine from the browser. In fact, if I run the following line:

```
shell_exec("whoami");
```

The following is returned when run through the browser or CLI: domain\gdesoto
which is correct and has administrative rights on the machine.

Is anyone able to successfully use the net use command when running a script through the browser? Or is there a concept that I'm missing that makes this impossible? Is there a better way to access a password protected network share?